# Enable CORS for AngularJS application on YEOMAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gruntjs, http-headers, yeoman

I am trying to redirect my application to a payment gateway using $http post method

below is the code:

```
$http.post("payment api",paymenttrans,
{headers: { 'content-type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'X-App-Token':payment token }})
.then(function (success){
     //some code
},function (error){
     //some code
 });
```

grunt file is as below :

```
grunt.initConfig({
 connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',`enter code here`
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I am getting an error stating that :

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at **Payment page**. (Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Need help on this with Grunt configuration or server configuration

Web server : NGINX.

Application Server : Puma.

Language : Ruby on Rails.

I have tried solutions like https://gist.github.com/Vp3n/5340891 which didn't help my problem.